# How to use function members of a class recursively?

Tags: c++, recursion

How can you define a function of a class to be recursive?, this is what I have been doing:

```
class A
{
 private:
  
 public:
  _recursive(A *var);
  recursive()
}

A::recursive()
{
  _recursive(this)
}

A::_recursive(A *var)
{
  _recursive(var->next);
}
```

And on main:

```
A *temp = new A();
A->recursive();
```

I have also tried (same class as before)

```
A *temp = new A();
A->_recursive(&A);
```

There seems like this should be something somebody else has found and easier or more elegant way of doing so, I tried making the class simple just to demonstrate, but this is a single linked list transverse program so it needs recursion.

Comment: _"... but this is a single linked list transverse program so it needs recursion."_ Not really.

Comment: You define a recursive function by letting it call itself.

Comment: it is unclear why you think you need to pass `this` explicitly. Actually your confusion is not related to recursion. `_recursive` already has access to `this` you need not pass it again.

Comment: `void A::do_something() { if (next) next->do_something(); }`?

Comment: maybe you removed too much from your example such that the actual problem you encountered is not present anymore. I suggest to go back to the real code and try to create a [mcve] that includes the actual issue

Comment: Your function `recursive()` is not recursive (not withstanding the name) but simply calls `_recursive()`.   `_recursive()` calls itself so is, by definition, recursive.   The problem is that `_recursive()` unconditionally calls itself, so never returns, and is infinitely recursive (i.e. it keeps calling itself and never returns).   You need to change its logic to something akin to `A::_recursive(A *var) {if (some_condition()) _recursive(var->next);}` where `some_condition()` will be `false` - preferably after a finite number of recursive calls.

Answer (score 2):

Front-ending a recursive algorithm that, by its normative nature uses a parameterized gating is what I think you're *actually* trying to ask about. For a linked list, for example, given this procedural typical recursive solution where the descent is parameterized and the base-case is exit-on-null:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

void print_list(Node *p)
{
    if (!p)
        return;

    std::cout << p->data << ' ';
    print_list(p->next);
}
```

You can do the same thing with a member function by throwing that base logic in as a condition of the recursion. For example:

```
struct Node
{
    Node *next;
    int data;
    
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << data << ' ';
        if (next)
        {
            next->print();
        }
    }
};
```

The same modus-operandi can be extended to more complex structures like a BST node:

```
struct BSTNode
{
    BSTNode *left;
    BSTNode *right;
    int data;
    
    void inorder()
    {
        if (left)
            left->inorder();

        std::cout << data << ' ';

        if (right)
            right->inorder();
    }
};
```

At least I *think* that's what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

> this is a single linked list transverse program so it needs recursion.

You don't actually need a *recursive* loop at all. An *iterative* loop will suffice, and be safer for long lists as you won't run the risk of a stack overflow pushing each recursive call into the call stack (if you write the loop to use [tail-call recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), any decent compiler should be able to apply [tail-call optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/) to convert the recursive loop into an iterative loop), eg:

```
class A
{
 public:
  A *next;
  void doSomething();
}

A::doSomething()
{
  A* var = this;
  do {
    // do something with var...
    var = var->next;
  }
  while (var);
}
```